# CSV output not saving results correctly

Tags: python, csv

Python beginner here seeking some guidance from the dev gods. I am having issues saving the output to a CSV file, the current output is not saving all the data and does not correctly count each row ID (0,1,2,3,etc) in the CSV. Any suggestions?

Current Code:

```
def get_length(file_path):
    with open("data.csv", "r") as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        reader_list = list(reader)
        return len(reader_list)

def append_list(file_path,stock_status,stock_name,date_time):
    fieldnames = ['id','stock status','stock name','date/time']
    next_id = get_length(file_path)
    with open(file_path, "a+") as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writerow({
            "id": next_id,
            "stock status": stock_status,
            "stock name": stock_name,
            "date/time": date_time,
        })

def check_add_cart():
    try:
        browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[normalize-space()="Add to Cart"]')
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False
    return True

cycle = 2
with open('url.txt', 'r') as f:
    url_list = [line.strip() for line in f]

for i in range(cycle): 
    for url in url_list:
        browser.get(url)
        time.sleep(6)
    if check_add_cart():
        append_list("data.csv", "In-Stock =)", browser.title, now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    elif not check_add_cart():
        append_list("data.csv", "Out-Of-Stock =(", browser.title, now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    else:
        print('Error')
browser.close()
```

Current CSV Output:

```
0,Out-Of-Stock =(,Sony PlayStation 5 Console,2021-06-05 17:45:01

2,Out-Of-Stock =(,Sony PlayStation 5 Console,2021-06-05 17:45:01
```

Desired CSV Output:

```
0,Out-Of-Stock =(,Sony PlayStation 5 Console,2021-06-05 17:45:00
1,In-Stock =),AMD Ryzen 5 5600x 4th Gen 6 Core 12 Threads,2021-06-05 17:45:01
2,Out-of-Stock =(,EVGA Geforce Rtx 3080 XC3,2021-06-05 17:45:02
3,Out-Of-Stock =(,Gigabyte Nvidia Geforce RTX 3080,2021-06-05 17:45:03
```

Comment: was the else print('error') called?

Comment: Nope it was not printed on terminal

Comment: Try changing to: `with open(file_path, "a+", newline='') as csvfile:`  That should remove the extra blank lines and might help with your `get_length()` routine. Ideally that should not be counting blank lines.

Comment: Also, providing a [Minimal Reproducing Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) helps to answer. Because we don't have the input CSV file, we can't run your script to reproduce the problem, and check that a solution is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you doing 2 cycles ?

And I think the error is that

```
if check_add_cart():
        append_list("data.csv", "In-Stock =)", browser.title, now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    elif not check_add_cart():
        append_list("data.csv", "Out-Of-Stock =(", browser.title, now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    else:
        print('Error')
```

should be indented into the `for url in url_list:` loop, otherwise it is only executed once per cycle, for the last url of the list.